# Remove new line character from the middle of a file line in java

Tags: java

I would like to remove  the new line character in the middle of a line of a file while it is reading the file.

If I'm going to read the file with BufferedReader then it is recognised as a new line and split the line in the middle. I want to be able to read the file and remove those new line characters of the middle while reading.
The format of each line is a simple Json.

Thank you

Comment: I am a bit slow. A `BufferedReader` will read lines using `readLine()` discarding the terminating newline. One can write to a _second_ file, write every line followed by writing a newline except for the middle. Or what?

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If each line is simple Json, can't you just parse it with a Json parser? Please give an example of your input so we can understand your problem.

Comment: Probably I understand it wrong: You are saying, there is a new line character in the middle of a line? That ist not possible, because than you have two lines. Or do you read some bytes into a buffer and want get rid of the newline characters? Than simply use readLine() instead of read.

Answer (score 1):

If what youre saying is you want to remove the newlines from the original file after reading them, I think you can just write to a new (temporary) file while youre reading the lines, and then replace the file with the original after youre done writing.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, what you want to do isn't quite as simple as "read and write at the same time". What you need is a loop and a `StringBuilder`.

```
public String readFileWithNoLines(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Then you want to write the return value of that function to the file.